# AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'route'

Tags: python, flask

**attendanceproject/app/__init.py__**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import dbmodels, routes, forms
```

**attendanceproject/app/routes.py**

```
from app import app
from app import db
from flask import render_template,url_for,session,request
import app.forms

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/signin.html',methods=['GET','POST'])
def signin():
    form=Signinform()
    if request.method=='POST':
        if form.validation==False:
            flash("Please enter all the fields")
            return render_template('signin.html',form=form)
```

**attendanceproject/run.py**

```
from app import app
from app import db
import app.dbmodels

db.create_all()
app.run(debug=True)
```

**error thrown**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "D:\Python projects\attendance project\app\__init__.py", line 11, in     <module>
    from app import dbmodels, routes, forms
  File "D:\Python projects\attendance project\app\routes.py", line 6, in <module>
    @app.route('/index')
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'route'
```

In need of assistance . i can't quite get why the error!!

Comment: The issues lies within this line `from app import dbmodels, routes, forms`...I don't see `dbmodels` in `__init__.py` file and even `routes`...`forms`...This is making me confused?